# Adding ListItems to Session

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

There are examples here on Stackflow on how to add ListBox items to the session and then repopulate the items back to the ListBox but for some reason it is not working.

Here's the code snippet

```
Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click

    If lstFields.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To lstFields.Items.Count - 1
            If lstFields.Items(i).Selected Then
                If Not arrayFields.Contains(lstFields.Items(i)) Then
                    arrayFields.Add(lstFields.Items(i))
                    Session("items") = arrayFields
                End If
            End If
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To arrayFields.Count - 1
            If Not lstSelected.Items.Contains((CType(arrayFields(i), ListItem))) Then
                lstSelected.Items.Add((CType(arrayFields(i), ListItem)))
            End If

            lstFields.Items.Remove((CType(arrayFields(i), ListItem)))
        Next

        lstSelected.SelectedIndex = -1        

End Sub
```

When I try to repopulate the items back to ListBox using the For Each loop, the error I kept getting using VS 2015 that shows:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in FocusVB.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Here's the snippet of the for each loop:

```
For Each item As ListItem In Session("item")
   lstSelected.Items.Add(New ListItem(item.Text, item.Value))
Next
```

Am I missing somewhere in the code?

Comment: What is the type of lstSelected? Have you tried casting the items to ListBox as you add them to the session to see if you get the same invalid cast exception?

Comment: `InvalidCastException` means that you are trying to cast one type of object to another which is not supported .... Here your easy fix is remove `ListItem` from the line `For each item as listitem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `ListItem` from the line `For each item as listitem` ..

```
 For Each item In Session("item")
```

lstSelected.Items.Add(New ListItem(item.Text, item.Value))
    Next

Don't ask me why ,rather read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx) .Take a look at the namespace of it,it'll answer you(if you are not talking about `System.Windows.Documents.listItem`)

Comment: It's weird lol....`ListItem` is a different object type rather than something u are looking for...that's why it works lolz

Answer (score 1):

Your enumerated list contains Session("items") = arrayFields

However, your reference is item, not items.  Change to items.

```
If Not  Session("items") Is Nothing Then
    For Each item As ListItem In Session("items")
        lstSelected.Items.Add(New ListItem(item.Text, item.Value))
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo!

Comment: This wouldn't work , the error would still be there , please read my answer to find out why ... Hope this enriches ur knowledge

Comment: Yes, something has to do with differentiating object types.